# XOR-encrypting list of integers with a string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to create a XOR-function in Python3 in  order to solve an online challenge. However, I'm struggling to understand the concept of how a cipher is applied to a list of integers. Consider the list

```
numlist = [36,22,80,0,0,4,23,25]
```

and the cipher (encryption key)

```
"abc"
```

Is the proper way to apply the cipher to the list to loop through the list like this? (36 will be xorred with "a", 22 with "b", 80 with "c" and 80 with "a" again?)

```
for i in range(0, len(numlist)):
    numlist[i] ^= ord("abc"[i%3])
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on your question? What is the challenge? What do you mean by cipher?

Comment: @ARK1375 the cipher is the encryption key, I edited the question. I was wondering how  to encode or decode the list with the key. The problem is Project Euler #59 - I think I have the solution method figured out but this is the concept I can't grasp.

Comment: Its mentioned in the question: "If the password is shorter than the message, which is likely, the key is repeated cyclically throughout the message."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of algorithms out there that you can use to cipher a given string (in this matter your `numlist`) using a key. For example, your key could be the position of the routers in an enigma machine or it can be the key for a simple Caesar cipher. So It depends on your encryption (ciphering) algorithm.
About the code snippet that you implemented, I can say that this is **One** right method to do it. It's called the XOR cipher. Your implementation is correct. And If you want to be sure, you can reapply your code to the numlist again and verify that it returns your original input.

```py
>>> numlist = [36,22,80,0,0,4,23,25]

>>> for i in range(0, len(numlist)):
        numlist[i] ^= ord("abc"[i%3])

>>> numlist
[69, 116, 51, 97, 98, 103, 118, 123]

>>> for i in range(0, len(numlist)):
        numlist[i] ^= ord("abc"[i%3])

>>> numlist
[36, 22, 80, 0, 0, 4, 23, 25]
```

This is because if `A XOR B = C` then `B XOR C = A`.

Answer (score 1):

if you want `Encrypte` and `Decrypte` you can first xor with chars that you want second run encryption on `encrypted-array` then get decrypted array, see this example:

```
numlist = [36,22,80,0,0,4,23,25]

# Encrypted
for i in range(0, len(numlist)):
    numlist[i] ^= ord("abc"[i%3])  
print(numlist)

# Decrypted
for i in range(0, len(numlist)):
    numlist[i] ^= ord("abc"[i%3]) 
print(numlist)
```

output:

```
[69, 116, 51, 97, 98, 103, 118, 123]
[36, 22, 80, 0, 0, 4, 23, 25]
```